# Is it possible to force Views to collect a minimum count of nodes per group?

Tags: search, views

I have a View that collects nodes of a certain type, grouped by term.

```
Term 1
 Node 1
 Node 3
 Node 4
 ...
Term 2
 Node 2
 Node 5
 ...
```

Can I force Views to list exactly 10 nodes per each term, rather than total of ten per entire query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Views Grouping Row Limit](http://drupal.org/project/views_limit_grouping) module.

From the project page:

> This is a basic Views style plugin that allows for a limit on the number of rows displayed within a grouping field.